# Python : How to generate dates in multiples of 2?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Here I am trying to generate list dates in multiples of 2.

```
# input : current date: 01-10-2020 
# Output: list_of_dates =[02-10-2020,04-10-2020,08-10-2020,16-10-2020,01-11-2020,02-12-2020]

#pseudo code
current_date = 01-10-20
squence = [1,2,4,8,16,32,64]
date_list = []

for i in range(len(sequence)):
    current_date = current_date + a[i]
    date_list.append(current_date)
```

After 16-10-2020 I need to get 01-11-2020 and so.. how can this be done ?

Comment: please accept Jezrael’s solution or my solution by clicking the check mark. Also, please upvote if helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tagged as pandas but if you wanted to do a python loop as you have posted in your question, then you can do this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
current_date = datetime.strptime('01-10-20', '%d-%m-%y')
squence = [1,2,4,8,16,32,64]
date_list = []

for i in squence:
    current_date = current_date + timedelta(days=i)
    date_list.append(current_date.strftime('%d-%m-%y'))
date_list
Out[1]: 
['02-10-20',
 '04-10-20',
 '08-10-20',
 '16-10-20',
 '01-11-20',
 '03-12-20',
 '05-02-21']
```

Answer (score 1):

Loops are here not necessary, convert sequence to timedeltas and add to datetime, also added `np.cumsum` for cumulative sum of values in `sequence`:

```
current_date = '01-10-20'
sequence = [1,2,4,8,16,32,64]

date_list = (pd.to_timedelta(np.cumsum(sequence), unit='d') + 
             pd.to_datetime(current_date, format='%d-%m-%y'))
print (date_list)
DatetimeIndex(['2020-10-02', '2020-10-04', '2020-10-08', '2020-10-16',
               '2020-11-01', '2020-12-03', '2021-02-05'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)


date_list_str = date_list.strftime('%d-%m-%y').tolist()
print (date_list_str)
['02-10-20', '04-10-20', '08-10-20', '16-10-20', '01-11-20', '03-12-20', '05-02-21']
```

Comment: @DavidErickson - yop, added `np.cumsum` for correct output.